# jQuery: Checked event on checkbox added later through innerHTML is not working.

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two checkboxes in my page for which the change event I'm capturing in the below code:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
 alert('hello '+this.checked);
 });
```

But if I add third checkbox to that group and I click this checkbox, the above function is not triggered.

I am adding the third checkbox to the group through the innerhtml code like below:

```
 var text2='<li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="TRUE"/><a    href="#"> New function</a></li>';
 text1=text1+' '+ text2;
 parent.innerHTML=text1;
```

Note: text1 is the existing innerhtml code of existing two checkboxes.

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation. Use `on` method.

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

```
$('document/ParentSelector').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
    alert('hello ' + this.checked);
});
```

Just update your `parentSelector` in the code above and it should work.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function of jQuery for run time added element:

```
$(document).on('change',':checkbox',function(){
 alert('hello '+this.checked);
 });
```

Comment: What wrong is in it?

Comment: It will not work for dynamically added checkboxes

Comment: This is not event delegation, better see the others posted

Comment: @Tushar have you tried it? it will work

Comment: @FatalError Did YOU try that

Comment: @Tushar yes, and it works

Comment: @FatalError Come On! You updated the code in between

Comment: Hi FatalError, I've tried this but it didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

Important point here is when you are using .on to attache event as per the below code it attach event to both static and dynamically added control , so there is no need to of function you writtne on will do the work of attached function to all element(static or dynamic).

---

if you are adding checkbox at runtime i.e. after page get created than you need to use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function of jquery to attache function

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );

var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
  $( "div" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
};
```

in simple you can do this

```
$('document').on("change", "input:checkbox", function() {  
                alert('hello '+this.checked);});
```

or try

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
    if (!this.checked) {

    }
});
```

jsfiddle for this : http://jsfiddle.net/m77sN/112/

Comment: I've tried all these options but still it didnt work. do we need change event for earlier checkboxes and on event for dynamically added checkboxes?

Comment: @Rain - can you please provide your code in jsfiddler ...http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi Pranay, whats your mailid. I can send the file to you.

Comment: Basically I think the issue is on event is not working at all with my code even though I wrap it inside document.ready function. I tried many different ways to write the signature of this on event.     $(document).ready(function() {   
$(document).on("change", ":checkbox", function() {  
$(':checkbox').on('change', function(){  
$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {

Comment: @Rain - you can check this its working aslo helpful for you...http://jsfiddle.net/m77sN/

Comment: unfortunately i do not have id of the checkbox. can I use it through CSS or input type checkbox options?

Comment: @Rain - yes or you can check this http://jsfiddle.net/m77sN/112/ which is using input:checkbox ...and if do work for you please accept answer and mark as selected

Answer (score 0):

Use `Event delegation` in the context for adding dynamic created elements in the dom there are many examples in SO

```
$(document).on('change' , ':checkbox', function(){
    alert('hello '+this.checked);
 });
```